# How can i prompt two commands in one click? pl/sql oracle 10g forms bulider

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

[image]

See Image please,
There's no error, but the first command executed and the form is not exiting.
help please

updated photos for the problem
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dASmO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `exit_form(do_commit);` to perform both two commands together.

**EDIT** : You can add the following inside `ON-MESSAGE` trigger at forms level :

```
if message_code = 40401 Then 
    null; 
end if;
```

*to suppress that message.*

Comment: Right; or modify message level, e.g. `:system.message_level := 25; exit_form(do_commit); :system.message_level := 0;`

Answer (score 1):

`EXIT_FORM` exits the form, normally. It does not if form is currently in enter query mode. In such a case, `exit_form` will just *cancel* query mode, i.e. it won't exit the form. So, are you in enter query mode?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didnt understand what do you mean by in query mode, the pic ubove dosn't show anything is running, all before run,

Comment: *Enter query mode* is mode you enter by pressing F7 (or using the form menu) which expects user to enter search criteria; then it presses the *execute query* button (or key shortcut (F8) or use appropriate menu item) so that form fetches data (that meet the search criteria) from the database. When you're in *entery query mode*, it is stated in form's status bar (the bottom line of the form window).

Comment: It is a message raised by COMMIT, saying that there's nothing to save into the database. Do you know how to use debugger? While in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger, right-click the left margin and set the breakpoint. Then run the form in debug mode (it is a green icon next to the one you normally use to run a form). Once you push the button, it'll start the debugger so you'd be able to trace forms' execution.